# Ctrl+Alt+F1 doesn't open TTY

Tags: gnome, virtual-console

I am trying to open a TTY by <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> combination, but instead, I see the Ubuntu login screen, like if I have just logged out.

[image: Something like this]

It is a problem for me as I'd like to run twm instead of Gnome, but I just can't access the tty.

SOLVED: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F5</kbd> was the combination I needed to access terminal "out of" X.

Comment: If you are talking about opening a terminal the keys are Ctrl+Alt+T The key strokes you mention do indeed take you to the login screen.

Comment: @User24601 I need to switch window manager to twm, and I cannot do that via Ctrl+Alt+T terminal, as it is inside the GUI I want to ged rid of.

Comment: Is Ctrl+Alt+F5 what you want?

Comment: @FedonKadifeli Yes!!! It surprised me I did not tried all the F's, as I was sure I did. Thank you very much for your help!